# Window name doesn't match

Tags: image, window

I been facing this problem for a long time and still have yet to solve it. As you can see in the image:

[image: hosted image UI]

The window's name is something like "-ka" BUT my program clearly named the window as "My Image".

I am now already doing more adavance stuff like splitting of image, etc, but my project supervisor asking me about this, yet I do not know the reason behind it. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anyone have such problem in the future and see this post, The reason was caused by it running in debug mode rather than release mode. Peace.